# Как заставить USB 3.0 перестать работать с 3.0 устройствами в 2.0 режиме?

Tags: linux, debian, usb, hdd, kernel

Итак ситуация: есть материнка без 3.0 портов. Была куплена PCI-E плата на 6 usb портов 2-3 (автоматический выбор) с доп. питанием (подключено).

Система ее видит lspci:

```
02:00.0 USB controller: Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720201 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 03)
```

Погуглил про нее, чип вроде NECовский. На сайте NEC в разделе с дровами такое:

> The Linux driver for the following Renesas USB device is released from
>   the Linux community site. It is included in Linux kernel. Please
>   download and use the current Linux Kernel from the Linux community
>   site, if you're using the Linux driver. Please contact to Linux
>   community, if you have a question regarding the Linux driver.

В ядре якобы есть поддержка. Ок, включаю модуль: # modprobe xhci_hcd Система начинает отлично видеть и работать со всем, что воткнуто в плату, но подозрительно медленно (внешний винт есть, работает с той же смешной скоростью, что и раньше). Смотрю дальше: lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 14cd:6116 Super Top M6116 SATA Bridge
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8564:1000  
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 14cd:8168 Super Top 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 09da:78b4 A4 Tech Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 1a2c:0c23 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 2109:0812  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
         Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0951:1666 Kingston Technology 
         Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bc2:3322 Seagate RSS LLC 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:8812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2109:2812  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
ага, винт 2:3, кстати флешка тоже должна 3.0 работать 2:4
```

lsusb -v -s 2:3

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bc2:3322 Seagate RSS LLC 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
             bcdUSB               2.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0bc2 Seagate RSS LLC
  idProduct          0x3322 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           2 
  iProduct                3 
  iSerial                 1 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           85
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           4
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     98 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
        Data-in pipe (0x03)
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
        Data-out pipe (0x04)
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
        Status pipe (0x02)
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x04  EP 4 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
        Command pipe (0x01)
```

lsusb -v -s 2:3

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bc2:3322 Seagate RSS LLC 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
             bcdUSB               2.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0bc2 Seagate RSS LLC
  idProduct          0x3322 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           2 
  iProduct                3 
  iSerial                 1 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           85
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           4
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     98 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
        Data-in pipe (0x03)
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
        Data-out pipe (0x04)
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
        Status pipe (0x02)
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x04  EP 4 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
        Command pipe (0x01)
```

$ lsusb -t

```
/:  Bus 12.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 11.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/3p, 12M
/:  Bus 10.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/3p, 12M
/:  Bus 09.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/3p, 12M
/:  Bus 08.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/3p, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
/:  Bus 07.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/4p, 480M
/:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
/:  Bus 05.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/6p, 480M
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=rtl8812au, 480M
                 Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
                 Port 4: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/6p, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 6, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
```

Судя по 2.1 и скорости в 480мбс (соответствует 2.0) железка упорно не хочет использовать весь свой потенциал. О системе $ uname -a

```
Linux desktop 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1 (2015-05-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Куда копать?

Comment: 1. у вас два раза приведён вывод одной и той же команды `lsusb -v -s 2:3`. 2. дополните для полноты картины выводом команд `sudo hdparm -t /dev/устройство` и `dd if=/dev/zero of=/новый/файл/на/примонтированном/устройстве/который/потом/можно/удалить bs=1G count=1`

Comment: 1. Извиняюсь. Вот по флешке вывод http://pastebin.com/bALNLjX8
2. $ sudo hdparm -t /dev/sdg1
<code>/dev/sdg1:
 Timing buffered disk reads: 106 MB in  3.05 seconds =  34.71 MB/sec</code>

 dd if=/dev/zero of=/media/ansy/5tb/tmp.file bs=1G count=1
<code>1+0 записей получено
1+0 записей отправлено
 скопировано 1073741824 байта (1,1 GB), 30,8443 c, 34,8 MB/c
</code>

Comment: да, скорость маловата. но, вполне возможно, «бутылочным горлышком» в вашем случае является не интерфейс usb, а интерфейс pci-e. я просто вспомнил, как года три назад разбирался с низкой производительностью wifi в какой-то модели роутера. адаптер был через pci-e шину подключен. так ребята с сайта openwrt помогли — нашли проблемы в «драйвере» шины. там то ли в алгоритме было дело, то ли в таймингах — я уже не помню. не исключён вариант, что у вас аналогичная проблема. а может быть нужны какие-то параметры коду, реализующему взаимодействие по шине. посмотрите в эту сторону.

Comment: учитывая, что устройства почему-то включаются в режиме 2.0, предположу, что дело не в шине. тут вопрос не только скорости, я ее и не замеряю, так как она от многого зависит, а от того, что явно прописан режим usb порта

Comment: *включаются в режиме 2.0* — тут вам виднее. я usb3-устройств в глаза не видел (контроллеры-то есть), и не ориентируюсь, что там про них должны показывать `lsusb` и прочие.

Comment: о! а вы в `dmesg` не заглядывали после подключения устройства? что там *linux* про него пишет? приложите, пожалуйста, эту информацию к вопросу. и ещё раз спрошу: это не ошибка, что у вас в вопросе два раза повторяется вывод lsusb для, вроде бы, одного и того же устройства? исправить вопрос можно, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: Ошибка. Случайно скопировал тот же фрагмент. Вот для флешки http://pastebin.com/bALNLjX8

dmesg ничего странного не пишет http://pastebin.com/UkEeqr3q

Comment: вот этот [драйвер](https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/issues/12). буквально на глазах решают проблему (если это не вы там участвуете в беседе).

Comment: не я. и я не понял, что делать с этим кодом..

Comment: там патч для usb_modeswitch.c. это из пакета usb-modeswitch. дистрибутивным путём это будет: 1. скачать и распаковать исходники пакета с помощью `apt-src`, 2. наложить патч (скорее всего, «чисто» он не наложится, надо будет несколько строк вручную вставить в нужные места). 3. собрать пакет с помощью `dpkg-buildpackage`. 4. установить его взамен дистрибутивного. 5. запусть программу с указанными там опциями. 6. если всё в порядке, usb3-устройства, подключенные к этому реалтековскому контроллеру, переключатся в usb3.

Comment: Realtek это usb wifi. В общем Есть новости. Вчера обновил ядро (apt-get upgrade) и флешка с хардом стали определяться как надо (bcdUSB 3.00). Получается, в предыдущем ядре не было поддержки? о_О А вот с realtek'ом засада, все так же 2.00. Кстати поставил ради эксперимента 4 ядро, там хард не подключается (то есть подключается, но в /dev не появляется. ошибки были с mtp и я снес, все что отвечало за mtp, usbmodeswitch тоже. не помогло. На текущем ядре все без изменений)

Answer (score 1):

проблема решена сменой ядра и переходом на mint